# Thread queue with multiple consumer

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm doing threaded queue with consumer getting items from queue and producer put items into queue. The number of consumer created is from user input. I tried following two ways. First version works well but the second is not. I cannot use first version because of user input constraint. Actually I didn't get the difference between the two. Is the first one creating three threads at the same time while second one create one by one? Any clue on this?

```
auto c1 = async(launch::async, consumer);
auto c2 = async(launch::async, consumer);
auto c3 = async(launch::async, consumer);

for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    auto c1 = async(launch::async, consumer);
```

Answer (score 1):

Both are, in a way, equal, as both starts three asynchronous tasks one after another.

Both are, in a way, different, as for the loop the variable `c1` is confined to a lifetime inside the loop and will go out of scope (and be destructed) every time the loop iterates. And it's probably this that makes all the difference: The object `c1` is destructed and have to wait for the `consumer` function to finish before it can be destructed.

Comment: Nice explanation. Then is there a way to change the second version a little bit so it can create three threads not waiting for consumer function to finish?

Comment: @user3081703 If you don't care for the result why not use [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) instead? And push them back into a vector so they're not destructed (and you can join them later when you need to).